# Difficulty getting the Font Awesome Brand icons to show up

Tags: reactjs, next.js, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to get a Font Awesome GitHub icon to show up on the client side, but it doesn't show up. I am using next.js, tailwind, and react.js to build my first portfolio. I have got the following dependencies in my package.json shown below

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
```

The font awesome icon is being imported in my Welcome.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faGithub} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
```

I have uploaded my folder structure.

[image]

I saw from other posts people used to import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"; but I am not sure where to put this.

I am still getting a hang of next.js so I hope someone can help me and see what I have done wrong... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have a `src` folder in the folder structure. I am assuming your Welcome.tsx file is inside that folder?

Usually with Next.js it is [preferred](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) to use the `pages` folder to render pages. You then create a `_app.tsx` inside the `pages` directory like below and this will import the styles. The `_app.tsx` folder is a place where you can add global styles to all the components, add loggers, analytics code etc. Anything added here affects all the components rendered.

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"; // Import the CSS
config.autoAddCss = false; // Tell Font Awesome to skip adding the CSS automatically since it's being imported above

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

If you decide to use the src folder to place your pages in, you should move your `app` directory to `src/app` like mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/src-directory). You might also want to change your tailwind configuration like [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations). I have not followed this structure before, so I looked this up in the documentation.